# Using keyboard on dell e5440 disables left click (but not trackpad)

Tags: mouse, windows-registry, touchpad

On my dell e5440 with an Alps touchpad, typing disables the trackpad left click for a second. This feature is annoying me but I cant seem to figure out how to disable it. I already disabled TouchGuard in the Dell Touchpad software [image]

And now I can move the cursor while typing but left click still stays disabled. I did some googling and found that swapping mouse buttons in windows fixes it, which it does, but now right click gets disabled for a second after typing. I tried editing registry to disable completely, by changing "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Alps\Apoint" SPTapTyping and SPTapTypingDelay to 0 but it made no difference. I tried looking through all the other registry keys in the Alps folder but none of them pop out to me. Does anyone have an idea of what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

mashuptwice answered this in a comment above.

In the Settings app, try to set the touchpad sensitivity to medium or higher –
mashuptwice

Setting it to Most sensitive worked